# Javascript variable declaration with brackets around initialized variables

Tags: javascript, syntax

In the React native website, there is the following line of code:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var { TabBarIOS, NavigatorIOS } = React;
```

In the second line of the example, what is the meaning of the brackets around the TabBarIOS and NavigatorIOS variables?

Comment: MDN Documentation: [Operators - Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a destructuring assignment.  It's a newer feature being brought in the ECMAScript 6 spec.

Here is an example object:

```
var test = {
  "hello": 1,
  "world": 2
}
```

If we deconstruct it like this:

```
var {hello, world} = test;
```

This is the equivalent to doing:

```
var hello = test.hello,
    world = test.world;
```

---

But, there is more fun stuff you can do with destructuring assignments...

Lets say we have this object:

```
var bucket = {
  ExampleObject: function(input){
    this.input = input.trim();
    return this.input;
  },

  TestingObject: function(example){
    this.example = example || {};
    console.log(this.example.input);
  }
}
```

Just for the record, I've given the members annoying names...  So when destructuring, we can rename them like this:

```
var {ExampleObject: Example, TestingObject: Test} = bucket;
```

The binding pattern follows a syntax like so:

```
{ObjectMemberName}
// Or
{ObjectMemberName: VariableName}
```

---

For more information, you can look at the [ECMAScript 6 specification draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-operations-on-promise-objects) or the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Also, I noticed you're a newer user...  If this post solved your question, you can check the green checkmark if you'd like.

Comment: Just getting used to this Syntax, Ive been away from front end Javascript for a while now, is the var{ExObj: Ex, TestObj: Test} = bucket;  Saying we are creating an instance of an object called bucket, and declaring two subclasses, ExObj and TestObj with the values Ex, and Test?